# Regex speed difference into code or console execution

Tags: python, regex, performance

I refine this expression in my python console:

```
texts = re.findall(r"text[^>]*\>(?P<text>(:?[^<]|</\s?[^tT])*)\</text", text)
```

It works very well and his execution time is nearly instant when i execute in the console, but when I put it into my code and execute via interpreter its seems to get blocked.

I test it again in the Console and it executed in less that a second again.

I check that the blocking sentence is the regex execution and the text is the same all the executions.

What is happening?

----------------------------------------code---------------------------------------------

```
class Wiki:
    # Regex definition
    search_text_regex = re.compile(r"text[^>]*\>(?P<text>(:?[^<]|</\s?[^tT])*)\</text")

def search_by_title(self, name, text):
        """ Search the slice(The last) of the text that contains the exact name and return               the slice index.
        """
        print "Backoff Launched:"
        # extract the tex from wikipedia Pages
        print "\tExtracting Texts from pages..."
        texts = self.search_text_regex.findall(text) # <= The Regex Launch
        # find the name in the text
        print "\tFinding names on text..."
        for index, text in enumerate(texts):
            if name in text:
                return index
        return None
```

-----------------Source----------------------------------

```
<page><title>Andrew Johnson</title><id>1624</id><revision><id>244612901</id><timestamp>2008-10-11T18:30:44Z</timestamp><contributor><username>Excirial</username><id>5499713</id></contributor><minor/><comment>Reverted edits by [[Special:Contributions/71.113.103.209|71.113.103.209]] to last version by Soliloquial ([[WP:HG|HG]])</comment><text xml:space="preserve">{{otherpeople2|Andrew Johnson (disambiguation)}}
{{Infobox President
|name=Andrew Johnson
|nationality=American
|image=Andrew Johnson - 3a53290u.png
|caption=President Andrew Johnson, taken in 1865 by [[Mathew Brady|Matthew Brady]].
|order=17th [[President of the United States]]
|vicepresident=none
|term_start=April 15, 1865
|term_end=March 4, 1869
|predecessor=[[Abraham Lincoln]]
|successor=[[Ulysses S. Grant]]
|birth_date={{birth date|mf=yes|1808|12|29}}
|birth_place=[[Raleigh, North Carolina]]
|death_date={{death date and age|mf=yes|1875|7|31|1808|12|29}}
|death_place=[[Elizabethton, Tennessee]]
|spouse=[[Eliza McCardle Johnson]]
|occupation=[[Tailor]]
|party=[[History of the Democratic Party (United States)|Democratic]] until 1864 and after 1869; elected Vice President in 1864 on a [[National Union Party (United States)|National Union]] ticket; no party affiliation 1865–1869
|signature=Andrew Johnson Signature.png
|order2=16th [[Vice President of the United States]]
|term_start2=March 4, 1865
|term_end2=April 15, 1865
|president2=[[Abraham Lincoln]]
|predecessor2=[[Hannibal Hamlin]]
|successor2=[[Schuyler Colfax]]
|jr/sr3=United States Senator
|state3=[[Tennessee]]
|term_start3=October 8, 1857
|term_end3=March 4, 1862
|preceded3=[[James C. Jones]]
|succeeded3=[[David T. Patterson]]
|term_start4=March 4, 1875
|term_end4=July 31, 1875
|preceded4=[[William Gannaway Brownlow|William G. Brownlow]]
|succeeded4=[[David M. Key]]
|order5=17th
|title5=[[Governor of Tennessee]]
|term_start5=October 17, 1853
|term_end5=November 3, 1857
|predecessor5=[[William B. Campbell]]
|successor5=[[Isham G. Harris]]
|religion=[[Christian]] (no denomination; attended Catholic and Methodist services)<ref>[http://www.adherents.com/people/pj/Andrew_Johnson.html Adherents.com: The Religious Affiliation of Andrew Johnson]</ref>
}}
Johnson was nominated for the [[Vice President of the United States|Vice President]] slot in 1864 on the [[National Union Party (United States)|National Union Party]] ticket.  He and Lincoln were [[United States presidential election, 1864|elected in November 1864]].  Johnson succeeded to the Presidency upon Lincoln's assassination on April 15, 1865.

==Bibliography==
{{portal|Tennessee}}
{{portal|United States Army|United States Department of the Army Seal.svg}}
{{portal|American Civil War}}
* Howard K. Beale, ''The Critical Year. A Study of Andrew Johnson and Reconstruction'' (1930). ISBN 0-8044-1085-2
*  Winston; Robert W. ''Andrew Johnson: Plebeian and Patriot'' (1928) [http://www.questia.com/PM.qst?a=o&d=3971949 online edition]

===Primary sources===
* Ralph W. Haskins, LeRoy P. Graf, and Paul H. Bergeron et al, eds. ''The Papers of Andrew Johnson'' 16 volumes; University of Tennessee Press, (1967–2000). ISBN 1572330910.) Includes all letters and speeches by Johnson, and many letters written to him. Complete to 1875.
* [http://www.impeach-andrewjohnson.com/ Newspaper clippings, 1865–1869]
* [http://www.andrewjohnson.com/09ImpeachmentAndAcquittal/ImpeachmentAndAcquittal.htm Series of [[Harper's Weekly]] articles covering the impeachment controversy and trial]
*[http://starship.python.net/crew/manus/Presidents/aj2/aj2obit.html Johnson's obituary, from the ''New York Times'']

==Notes==
{{reflist|2}}

==External links==
{{sisterlinks|s=Author:Andrew Johnson}}
*{{gutenberg author|id=Andrew+Johnson | name=Andrew Johnson}}
{{s-start}}
{{s-par|us-hs}}
{{s-aft|after=[[Ulysses S. Grant]]}}
{{s-par|us-sen}}
{{s-bef|before=[[James C. Jones]]}}
{{s-ttl|title=[[List of United States Senators from Tennessee|Senator from Tennessee (Class 1)]]|years=October 8, 1857{{ndash}} March 4, 1862|alongside=[[John Bell (Tennessee politician)|John Bell]], [[Alfred O. P. Nicholson]]}}
{{s-vac|next=[[David T. Patterson]]|reason=[[American Civil War|Secession of Tennessee from the Union]]}}
{{s-bef|before=[[William Gannaway Brownlow|William G. Brownlow]]}}
{{s-ttl|title=[[List of United States Senators from Tennessee|Senator from Tennessee (Class 1)]]| years=March 4, 1875{{ndash}} July 31, 1875|alongside=[[Henry Cooper (U.S. Senator)|Henry Cooper]]}}
{{s-aft|after=[[David M. Key]]}}
{{s-ppo}}
{{s-bef|before=[[Hannibal Hamlin]]}}
{{s-ttl|title=[[List of United States Republican Party presidential tickets|Republican Party¹ vice presidential candidate]]|years=[[U.S. presidential election, 1864|1864]]}}

{{Persondata
|NAME= Johnson, Andrew
|ALTERNATIVE NAMES=
|SHORT DESCRIPTION= seventeenth [[President of the United States]]<br/> [[Union (American Civil War)|Union]] [[Union Army|Army]] [[General officer|General]]
|DATE OF BIRTH={{birth date|mf=yes|1808|12|29|mf=y}}
|PLACE OF BIRTH= [[Raleigh, North Carolina]]
|DATE OF DEATH={{death date|mf=yes|1875|7|31|mf=y}}
|PLACE OF DEATH= [[Greeneville, Tennessee]]
}}

{{Lifetime|1808|1875|Johnson, Andrew}}
[[Category:Presidents of the United States]]
[[vi:Andrew Johnson]]
[[tr:Andrew Johnson]]
[[uk:Ендрю Джонсон]]
[[ur:انڈریو جانسن]]
[[yi:ענדרו זשאנסאן]]
[[zh:安德鲁·约翰逊]]</text></revision></page>
```

Comment: By *blocked* do you mean it doesn't return ever?

Comment: This sounds odd. Can you provide a complete, runnable example that we could experiment with?

Comment: What's your input `text` in both cases?

Comment: A side note about your expression: you probably want `?:`, not `:?` there. Also, `<text.*?>(.*?)</text>` looks simpler and would do the same.

Comment: I might be mistaken, but just in case you are trying to parse XML, HTML or XHTML using regexp, please have a look at http://is.gd/i28dPZ (it is the most popular answer to the most frequently asked question on Stackoverflow).

Comment: MattH: By blocked I mean that I kill the execution after 30 minutes.

aix: part of the code is from a Course of Coursera. I don't know if I have the rights to share it. I going to try extract the relevant part of the code.  

thg435: One of my previous attempt to extract the code is similar to this expression and it cant handle the text.

Alfe: Thanks, I no trying to parse XML I'm trying to extract one small part of it. In fact, I correctly extract it but when i put the sentence into a ".py " file it became slower than hell. That is my question: why is slower?

Comment: Can we have a bit of text to feed the code? It doesn't have to be big - if there is a performance issue (or if it blocks) it should be measurable anyway. Also, what version of python are we talking about and what platform?

Comment: I solve it. the code have a pipe for cleaning the text that remove.thanks for the help. How I mark the question as solved?

Comment: you can either post an answer yourself (i think there is a minimum waiting period, so you may need to wait before you can do this) or just delete the question by clicking on "close" below the question area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve it. 
The code have a pipe for cleaning the text that remove some necessary markup for correct matching. 
Because the length of the text, the search of a impossible match takes too much time.

Answer (score 0):

I would use this:

```
result = re.findall(r"(?s)<text[^>]*>(?P<text>(?:(?!</?text>).)*)</text>", subject)
```

`(?:(?!</?text>).)*` consumes one character at a time, but only after the lookahead verifies that it's not the first character of a `<text>` or `</text>` tag.